# Apache Nifi ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_6 consuming message from topic where key and value are avro serialized using confluent schema registry

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-nifi, avro, dataflow, confluent-schema-registry

I am using nifi to build a dataflow with the following setup:

- apache nifi 1.14.1
- kafka 2.13-2.7.1
- confluent schema registry

I am also using the processor ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_6 to process messages from a topic where the key and the value where both serialized using avro - schemas for the key and value are stored in the confluent schema registry. But the processor fails to parse the message because there is not a way - that I can see - to specify that both key and value are avro serialized with schemas stored in the confluent schema registry. The convention for naming the schema is usually [topic name]-value and [topic name]-key. I can read the messages just fine using kcat, formerly kafkacat using:

`kcat -b broker1:9092,broker2:9092,broker3:9092 -t mytopic -s avro -r http://schema-registry_url.com -p 0`

Is there a way to read such messages or am I supposed to add my own processor to nifi? Here's a trace of the error:

```
   causes: org.apache.nifi.serialization.MalformedRecordException: Error while getting next record. Root cause: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Malformed data. Length is negative: negative 62
     org.apache.nifi.serialization.MalformedRecordException: Error while getting next record. Root cause: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Malformed data. Length is negative: negative 62
        at org.apache.nifi.avro.AvroRecordReader.nextRecord(AvroRecordReader.java:52)
        at org.apache.nifi.serialization.RecordReader.nextRecord(RecordReader.java:50)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor559.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:254)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.access$100(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:38)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.service.StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler$ProxiedReturnObjectInvocationHandler.invoke(StandardControllerServiceInvocationHandler.java:240)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy192.nextRecord(Unknown Source)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumerLease.writeRecordData(ConsumerLease.java:549)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumerLease.lambda$processRecords$3(ConsumerLease.java:342)
        at java.util.HashMap$KeySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1556)
        at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:647)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumerLease.processRecords(ConsumerLease.java:329)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumerLease.poll(ConsumerLease.java:188)
        at org.apache.nifi.processors.kafka.pubsub.ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_6.onTrigger(ConsumeKafkaRecord_2_6.java:472)
        at org.apache.nifi.processor.AbstractProcessor.onTrigger(AbstractProcessor.java:27)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.StandardProcessorNode.onTrigger(StandardProcessorNode.java:1202)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.tasks.ConnectableTask.invoke(ConnectableTask.java:214)
        at org.apache.nifi.controller.scheduling.QuartzSchedulingAgent$2.run(QuartzSchedulingAgent.java:137)
        at org.apache.nifi.engine.FlowEngine$2.run(FlowEngine.java:110)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
     Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Malformed data. Length is negative: -62
        at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.doReadBytes(BinaryDecoder.java:336)
        at org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readString(BinaryDecoder.java:263)
        at org.apache.avro.io.ResolvingDecoder.readString(ResolvingDecoder.java:201)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readString(GenericDatumReader.java:430)
        at org.apache.nifi.avro.NonCachingDatumReader.readString(NonCachingDatumReader.java:51)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readMapKey(GenericDatumReader.java:335)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readMap(GenericDatumReader.java:321)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:177)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readField(GenericDatumReader.java:240)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readRecord(GenericDatumReader.java:230)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.readWithoutConversion(GenericDatumReader.java:174)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:152)
        at org.apache.avro.generic.GenericDatumReader.read(GenericDatumReader.java:144)
        at org.apache.nifi.avro.AvroReaderWithExplicitSchema.nextAvroRecord(AvroReaderWithExplicitSchema.java:92)
        at org.apache.nifi.avro.AvroRecordReader.nextRecord(AvroRecordReader.java:39)
        ... 27 common frames omitted
```

I am attaching pictures of the processor

- [ConsumeKafkaRecord 1 of 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uVJO1.png)
- [ConsumeKafkaRecord 2 of 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHvsA.png)
- [AvroReader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EGS5.png)
- [SchemaRegistry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ylW6S.png)

Comment: It appears you've configured NiFi to use plain avro deserializer, not the SchemaRegistry-based one. At least, I see no registry usage in that stacktrace

Comment: For the reader, you'll want to set "Confluent Content-Encoded Schema Reference" or perhaps "Embedded" option

Comment: Thanks for replying @OneCriketeer I did specify the confluent schema registry, look into AvroReader controller you will see it that picture and I am identifying the schema using the name, the issue is that there really are schemas albeit there is a convention for the naming which I followed.

Comment: Key attribute encoding you've set as strings (utf8)... Not Avro. For the values, you shouldn't need to specify what subject to use. The schema ID that's in the record bytes already knows what subject its associated with, so that's what the Confluent encoded option means https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-record-serialization-services-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.avro.AvroReader/index.html

Comment: Thanks again. The key attribute encoding is to select what encoding to use when nifi adds the key to the flowfile, even when I use "Do not add the key as attribute" I get the same error. There should be a way for me to specify that I am using an avro encoding for the key and I cannot see how to do that. In this case we would have 2 schemas ids one for the key and one for the value.

Comment: Yes, I understand you'll have two schemas. I was referring to your second Consume image that you've set the key decoder not as Avro.... If you try setting the schema version to latest, what happens? Or is that the default?

Comment: Thanks OneCricketeer. Thinking some more about your comments I went back and used Confluent Content-Encode Schema Reference and that did it. I did not need to mess with "Key atttibute" and such. It uses the topic name followed by value or key and that work like a charm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the data is already serialized correctly by some Confluent Serializer, you should prefer using the "**Confluent Content-Encoded Schema Reference**" option in the `AvroReader` since the Schema ID is embedded within the record and will get the correct subject/version, accordingly.

Otherwise, using the "Schema Name" or "Schema Text" value will either perform a lookup against the registry or use a literal, however, the deserializer will still expect a certain content-length of the record bytes, and seems to be the cause of the issue `Malformed data. Length is negative ...`